# How to click automatically on "Content" button

Tags: python, selenium, web, linkedin-api, screen-scraping

This is element HTML:

```
<button class="search-vertical-filter__filter-item-button button-tertiary-medium-muted" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-5975="5975"> Content </button>
```

Code:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Content').click()
```

Even i also tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('search-vertical-filter__filter-item-button button-tertiary-medium-muted').click()
```

I want to click on "Content" button on LinkedIn automatically and I am using Selenium and Python for that.

Comment: And, what happens when you run this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the following code:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".search-vertical-filter__filter-item-button.button-tertiary-medium-muted").click()
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: YES, U SOLVED MY PROBLEM THANK YOU BRO NOW MY TASK IS TO COPY LINKS FROM THE PAGE AUTOMATICALLY...... :)

Answer (score 1):

As per the *HTML* provided to click on the button with text as **Content** you can use the following line of code :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='search-vertical-filter__filter-item-button button-tertiary-medium-muted' and normalize-space()='Content']").click()
```

Comment: THIS IS HELPFUL TO ME BUT BY USING THIS CODE THEY DIRECT ME TO THE PEOPLE PAGE....